# Последовательный вывод значений из массива php после каждой перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, массивы, сессия

Добрый день! Я новичок в программировании. У меня возник теоретический вопрос. Есть массив со значениями. Я хочу показывать каждый раз новое значение из массива после каждой перезагрузки страницы пока не закончатся эти значения. Я знаю, что после перезагрузки страницы связь с сервером разрывается и данные теряются. Вопрос: как мне сделать так чтобы из массива (1, 2, 3, 4) После четырех перезагрузок страницы было последовательно выведено 1, 2, 3, 4. Спасибо.

Comment: Сохранить массив и/или указатель на текущий элемент в сессии http://php.net/manual/ru/features.sessions.php или в куках

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно на сервере сохранять последнее выданное число. Вариантов много.

1. Как сказал @uk141, можно использовать сессионные переменные. По ряду причин этот вариант имеет крайне узкую область применения. Так как будет привязан только к одной сессии со всеми вытекающими.
2. Можно использовать кеш и его [функцию инкремента](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.apcu-inc.php). Соответственно, при каждой перезагрузке сервера значение будет теряться.
3. Можно хранить значение в БД. Минусы в том, что придется использовать БД. Но мне этот вариант видится самым правильным.
4. Можно хранить значение в локальном файле. Но тут можно поплясать по граблям конкурирующего доступа.
5. Можно использовать суперглобальный массив $_SERVER. Плохой вариант, к тому же см. пункт 2

Answer (score 0):

В начале страницы `session_start();`, после этого у нас есть массив `$_SESSION[]`, который остается после перезагрузки страницы. В целом делать, примерно так:

Создаем сессию.

Проверяем наличие `$_SESSION['last']`.

Если нет - создаем и задаем значение `'0'`.

Если есть, увеличиваем на единицу.

Используем `$_SESSION['last']` как нам нужно.

Comment: Данный вариант имеет крайне ограниченную область применения.

Comment: Данный вариант полностью покрывает условия задачи.

Comment: Данный вариант не покрывает условия задачи в 3-х случаях. 1) Если запрос приходит от разных пользователей, 2) если сессия протухла, 3) если у клиента отключены куки

Comment: Хорошо. Вы правы. Мой вариант покрывает только те задачи, что родились в моем воображении.

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая, что запросы к серверу могут быть от многих клиентов, то что бы у каждого клиента это работало, данные нужно хранить на клиенте, то есть в куке, соответственно метод с сессией лучше всего подходит. Иначе если у кого то покажет 1, то у следующего клиента покажет уже 2. Либо если хранить в Базе данных или файле, то нужно сохранять с IP пользователя и потом делать выборку по IP, проверку и т.д. Таким образом можно обойтись без сессий и куки.