# Статистика игроков. PHP+SQL

Tags: php, sql

Нужно сделать что-то вроде текстовой трансляции матча. То есть, есть страница матча и в определённом блоке выводится хронология матч. Определенный игрок на определенной минуте получает карточку или забивает гол. И чтобы эти статистические данные сохранялись в определенной таблице, чтобы потом можно было вывести общую статистику. Есть идеи, как это можно организовать?

Comment: Я вижу это так. 1. Игровое поле должно содержать уникальный индикатор. 2. Допустим, матч идет 5 раундов. Тогда таблица выглядит таким образом. [ id ] [ 1 ] [ 2 ] ... [ 5 ]. 3. Теперь вы можете получит необходимые данные, а потом стереть данные.

Comment: А как именно мне данные матча считать и выводить в определенную таблицу?

Comment: Создать временные поля в таблице, а в них записывать каждый результат, после завершения раунда. После уже по id комнаты вы можете получить все необходимые данные и потом сопоставить их, как вам угодно.

Comment: Можете посмотреть на такую от браузерную игру barbars.ru, а именно обратите внимания на лог игры. Здесь скорее всего используется сессия, они могут кэшировать данные даже после перезагрузки страница. Вы бы могли хранить результаты раундом там же, в сессиях. если вам это подойдет.  Эта [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592491/Последовательный-вывод-значений-из-массива-php-после-каждой-перезагрузки-страниц) должна вам помочь, или подтолкнет.

Answer (score 0):

есть таблица матчи в котором дата и 2 индификатора комманд
есть таблица комманды, где собственно название команды и индификатор (страна если надо и еще какая-то мелкая информация)
есть таблица игроки ид, номер на футболке, имя, ид команды.(или если очень там варианты что игроки кочуют то таблица дополнительная должна быть с датой, ид комманды, ид игрока)
есть таблица статусов: перечисление возможных происшествий на поле.
есть таблица времени, в которой дата ид ирока, статус из таблицы выше, и связь с коммандой на которую этот статус влияет.

Вот так легонько взяли и разделили все на мелкие таблички, дальше осталось их заполнить.

Потом взять и написать пару простых выборок которые будут вам, что надо группировать и выводить.

В общем ничего такого сверх естественного просто правильно организуйте данные.

Comment: Немного не понял вот этот момент. "и связь с коммандой на которую этот статус влияет." Как именно он должен влиять на команду?

Comment: к примеру если это статус гол - он может быть забит себе, в остальном случаи думаю это лишнее поле, но все же по нему можно скажем построить группировку статистики статусов

Comment: Вы не подумайте, это не инструкция к исполнению, это я так увидел вашу задачу и быстренько набросал один из вариантов как можно не очень мучительно это все разделить

Comment: решил поискать в гугл https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/soccer-database-exercise/index.php здесь более детальная база их оказывается поисковик пару десятков решений выдает по вашей теме. Остальное - технически несложно, важно правильно БД сформировать, в большем случаи это будут выборки с join которые явно будут выдавать вам всю статистику вот еще https://github.com/openfootball/schema.sql